# Transaction done in Sandbox mode Authorize.Net

Tags: sandbox, authorize.net

We are using Authorize.net payment gateway. It is working in Production mode perfectly, recently by mistake we have changed the production mode to testing.

"PrimeAuthnetDeploymentMode.Testing"

Hence more customers done the payment in testing mode. I'm not sure about that, is the amount actually created from the customer account? How not sure what i have to do now? How can i get if the amount is amount is created from customer card?

Regards,
Karthik.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions submitting using test mode only confirms you are able to connect to the payment gateway.  It does not attempt a transaction and no record is kept of the request.